# "Write settings" permission not granted marshmallow android

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```

I have declared above line in my manifest ,and i ask for permission on activity start but unlike other permissions,after restarting my app,it again asks for permission.When i check if permission has been granted or not,i get result that says not granted for only this permission but when i checked the same thing with other permissions ,they are granted after the user has done so.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashScreen.this,PERMISSIONS, 1);
```

i check with :
EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this,PERMISSIONS)

Comment: did you tried in any other devices ?

Comment: I tried in my emulator

Comment: in both case you are having issue ?

Comment: yes,i just checked on LG nexus

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use this for write setting permission:

```
 public void settingPermission() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 200);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I ended with a similar code myself, but did you manage to get the result with `onActivityResult`? because when I pressed `Back` after giving permission, the result code I have is `RESULT_CANCELED`